# how create table with current_date always?

Tags: postgresql

i try this.

```
CREATE TABLE test (
    id INTEGER NOT NULL,
    other INTEGER,
    registered DATE GENERATED ALWAYS AS ( CURRENT_DATE ) STORED
);
```

but it gives me the following error

```
ERROR:  syntax error at or near "("
LINE 4:  registered DATE GENERATED ALWAYS AS ( CURRENT_DATE ) STORED
                                             ^
```

I want the field to not allow manual insertion and to be generated by the database

I have consulted [this documentation](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-createtable.html).

Comment: That statement should generate an error like "ERROR: generation expression is not immutable", not a syntax error. You can't do this with a generated column. You will need a trigger to do this.

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name what would the trigger be like? respecting the fact that they cannot manually insert data into that column(registered)

Comment: You must not create generated column but set DEFAULT VALUE for common static column. See "DEFAULT *default_expr*" clause description in the article by your link.

Comment: It's unclear to me if that column should only store the value when a new row is inserted and then never change or if this should be update automatically if the row changes (which is what a generated column is for)

Answer (score 0):

The `spi` extension has a trigger function called `moddatetime` that updates a given column with the current time stamp when called. I use it for all my updated-at columns in my tables.